# Sapi voice PAUSING error : pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2147201018), None)

Tags: python, text-to-speech, pywin32, sapi

I just wnat to make an app that tts(convert text to speech) text so i found Sapi voice is a good lib for this. It works well when I run the 'start_speacking' function in a thread. BUT, when I pause the speaker and wait for about 5-15 seconds I get this error below...

```
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2147201018), None)
```

- my code
- 

```
import threading
import time
import win32com.client
import pythoncom


speaker = win32com.client.Dispatch("SAPI.SpVoice")


def start_speaking():

    global speaker

    pythoncom.CoInitialize()
    speaker.Speak('hello world hello world hello world')




thread = threading.Thread(target=start_speaking)
thread.start()
time.sleep(1)
speaker.Pause()
```

Comment: Just a suggestion but you may be having issues because you are trying to use the same object from two threads. Usually the default COM threading is apartment-threaded, which means that an object should only be accessed from one thread (which is also why you need CoInitialize() in the worker thread). You may need to initialize COM as mutli-threaded?

Comment: I tried to follow this documentation 'https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/initializing-the-com-library' to use COM as multi-threaded but it always fails and I get the same error,